# Custom Scalar in Graphql-java

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

We are planning use Graphql as backend server in our application. We choose Graphql-Java to develop our POC. We came across a stituation to create our own  scalartype to handle java.util.Map object type.

we havent found any documentation regarding creating a custom scalar type.
In example code as below

```
RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring() {
    return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
            .scalar(CustomScalar)
```

how to was the implementation done for CustomScalar object.
need help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a general idea how to make a scalar, just take a look into [the existing ones](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/Scalars.java) and do something similar.

graphql-java also has a separate project for extra scalars: [graphql-java-extended-scalars](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars). And there you can find the [object scalar (a.k.a. JSON scalar)](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars#object--json-scalars), that can be used for dynamic structures, like `Map`s.

Register it via:

```
RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring().scalar(ExtendedScalars.Object)
```

Comment: how do I utilize above scaler into my code? I've a Spring-boot application and it'll help if you could provide an example.

Comment: @Simple-Solution How do you use any built-in scalar, like String or Integer? There's no difference.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. But those; String and Integer are built in and it all happens automatically. So above scalar is for object and I would need to create one for Map, right? Do you've an example. Also what is the significant of the `name` argument? Is that the name of the type we defined in the schema?

Comment: @Simple-Solution Happens automatically? Does that mean you're using GraphQL-SPQR? If so, annotate the type at the place of use with `@GraphQLScalar` (e.g. annotated a method argument) or use a different `ScalarMappingStrategy` (e.g. `gen.withScalarMappingStrategy(new MapScalarStrategy())`).
Without SPQR, there's no automatic mapping. You set a type of each field, e.g. `newFieldDefinition().type(Scalars.GraphQLString)`, so you can use `newFieldDefinition().type(Scalars.graphQLObjectScalar("typeName"))` instead. You'll get a `Map` just like for any object input, but with a dynamic structure.

Comment: @Simple-Solution If using schema-first with graphql-java directly, you can use a custom scalar via `RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring().scalar(Scalars.graphQLObjectScalar("typeN‌​ame"))`. Mind you, in the 2nd and the 3rd example `Scalars` is `io.leangen.graphql.util.Scalars` not `graphql.Scalars`. Or just copy the SPQR code into your own class.

Comment: Never knew `GraphQL-SPQR` existed, I'm using Code-first approach, where I've a `schema.graphqls` file which holds my type/api definition. Do you know how does that fit into my approach? Here is another question i asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677140/graphql-schema-equivalent-of-this-json/47691101?noredirect=1#comment82347617_47691101

Comment: @Simple-Solution If you have a schema in a file, that's a schema-first approach. And I've given you the exact literal code you need to add. I can't help you further. You seem to need some more reading of the docs first.

Comment: Where do you guys declare this class. I follow the example of http://graphql-java.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scalars.html where `public static class EmailScalar` is declared but the compiler fails because it is not allowed to just declare a static class anywhere. I cannot find the explaination where to declare this class actually

Comment: @xetra11 It's an instance of `GraphQLScalarType`, not a class. And who says it needs to be static?

Answer (score 0):

In code first approach (SPQR v0.9.6) adding **@GraphQLScalar** is enough.
Or, as alternative, add scalar definition to GraphQLSchemaGenerator:

```
new GraphQLSchemaGenerator()
.withScalarMappingStrategy(new MyScalarStrategy())
```

And define MyScalarStrategy:

```
class MyScalarStrategy extends DefaultScalarStrategy {

@Override
public boolean supports(AnnotatedType type) {
  return super.supports(type) || GenericTypeReflector.isSuperType(MyScalarStrategy.class, type.getType());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add dependency in your pom file

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-scalars</artifactId>
  <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then write a class to register scalar Component

```
@Configuration

public class ScalarRegister {

   @Bean
    public RuntimeWiring.Builder addLongScalar(RuntimeWiring.Builder builder) {
        return builder.scalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong);
    }

}
```

Then, you can use the Long Scalar, which means the Long type. Several scalar types are available, including **GraphQLChar, GraphQLLong, GraphQLBigInteger, Currency, Url, Json, and LocalTime**.   from creating beans you can extend the scalars