# GraphQL schema equivalent of this Json?

Tags: json, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java

I'm newbie to GraphQL, and was wondering if someone could help me figure out what is the equivalent of below JSON into GraphQL schema:

```
[
 {
   "id": "1",
   "name": "A",
   "fldDef": [
    {
      "name": "f1",
      "type": "str",
      "opt": false
    },
    {
      "name": "f2",
      "type": "bool"
    }]
 },
 {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "B",
    "fldDef": [
     {
       "name": "f3",
       "type": "str",
       "opt": true
     },
     {
       "name": "f4",
       "type": "str",
       "opt": true
     }]
  }
]
```

So far I managed to map above response to below object:

```
  public class FldDef {

     private String name, type;
     private boolean opt;
     // getters & setters
 } 

 public class Product {

    private String id, name;
    private Map<String, FldDef> fldDef;

   // getters & setters

 }
```

Then my schema looks like below, but the problem I'm having is as a part of `Product` object, I've a `Map` which I would like to get the schema right for it, but I'm having difficulty getting the schema right!

```
type FldDef { 
   name: String!
   type: String!
   opt: Boolean!
} 

type Product {
   id: String!
   name: String!
   fldDef: FldDef! // now here I don't know what is the syntax for representing MAP, do you know how to achieve this?
 }
```

I get below exception:

`Causedby:com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.TypeClassMatcher$RawClassRequiredForGraphQLMappingException: Type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.grapql.research.domain.FldDef> cannot be mapped to a GraphQL type!  Since GraphQL-Java deals with erased types at runtime, only non-parameterized classes can represent a GraphQL type.  This allows for reverse-lookup by java class in interfaces and union types.`

Note: I'm working with Java eco-system (graphql-java)

Answer (score 0):

giving you a schema from your JSON is not really possible because a schema contains much more information than just simply the shape of your data. I think the best for you would be to learn the basics of GraphQL, designing simple schemas is then very easy and fun! Maybe start with the learning section on [graphql.org](http://graphql.org). They have a section about the [schema](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/). Basically you build your schema from scalars (aka primitives) and object types. All types can additionally be wrapped in the non-nullable type and/or of the list type. GraphQL was designed for clients. The easiest way of understanding GraphQL is making some queries against an existing API. [Launchpad](https://github.com/apollographql/launchpad) has a lot of examples that you can use (and modify when you know some JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I know the basic. I've also updated my question so that it gives you more context!

Comment: Unfortunately I have only worked with the Node.js and Scala GraphQL implementations. First: Your schema looks good but you will need a Query type that offers an entry point to the system. Second: GraphQL does not have maps! Instead you would use a list with IDs or keys.  make `fldDef` on Product a list, like so `[FldDef!]!` and probably a list type (like array list) in Java to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some changes as below:

Schema definition:

```
type FldDef {
   name: String!
   type: String!
   opt: Boolean!
}

type Product {
   id: String!
   name: String!
   fldDef: [FldDef]! // make it as Collection of FldDef
 }
```

Java Class:

```
public class FldDef {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private boolean opt;
    // getters & setters
}

public class Product {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<FldDef> fldDef; // Change to List of FldDef
    // getters & setters
}
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks I know this but that’s not an answer but rather a suggestion or comment! A solution is to implement a CustomScalar for a Map, which I’ve implemented it!

Comment: I would strongly advice against the custom scalar solution since you lose the statically typed property of GraphQL and the ability to define subselections, which is the reason why you are using GraphQL in the first place.