# Custom Scalar Type in graphql-spqr

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-spqr

I graphql-spqr, java.util.Date is defined as Scalar. Is it possible to overwrite the serialization/deserialization of java.util.Date to get a different String representation of the date?

The ScalarStrategy mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034801/custom-scalar-in-graphql-java) was removed with the latest release.

```
public class Order {

    private String id;
    private Date orderDate; //GraphQLScalarType "Date"

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(String id, String bookId, Date orderDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }
}
```

GraphQL Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createOrder": {
      "id": "74e4816c-f850-4d63-9855-e4601fa125f4",
      "orderDate": "2019-05-26T08:25:01.349Z", // --> 2019-05-26
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Added a code sample to my answer. Not perfect, but the best I can do on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScalarStrategy` isn't the proper way to achieve what you want. When you want to change how a Java type gets mapped to GraphQL, you normally provide a new (or customize an existing) `TypeMapper`.

Take a look at the existing `Date` scalar implementation and implement your own in a similar way. Then implement a custom `TypeMapper` that simply always returns a static instance of that scalar from both `toGraphQLType` and `toGraphQLInputType` methods.

```
public class CustomTypeMapper implements TypeMapper {

    private static final GraphQLScalarType GraphQLCustomDate = ...;

    @Override
    public GraphQLOutputType toGraphQLType(...) {
        return GraphQLCustomDate;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphQLInputType toGraphQLInputType(...) {
        return GraphQLCustomDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(AnnotatedType type) {
        return type.getType() == Date.class; // This mapper only deals with Date
    }
}
```

To register it, call `generator.withTypeMappers(new CustomTypeMapper()`.

That said, since you're only trying to cut off the time part, you'd ideally use `LocalDate` here. You can make SPQR do that transparently by registering a `TypeAdapter` (which is nothing but a mapper + converter) but a simple mapper as explained above is a more efficient solution in your case. If you still decide to go the adapter way, you can inherit `AbstractTypeAdapter<Date, LocalDate>` and implement the conversion logic (should be trivial). Register via `generator.withTypeAdapters` or by registering it as a mapper and converters separately.