# How to treat a child class like its parent in GraphQL SPQR

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

I created a wrapper around BigDecimal. Basically just putting a bunch of friendlier methods on top of it. I use it for some of my POJO's fields, and it generates a schema like this

```
# Built-in java.math.BigDecimal
scalar BigDecimal

input BestDecimalInput {
  scale: Int!
}
```

Ideally, when I go to make a query I'd be able to treat it the same as BigDecimal. I have a constructor

```
public BestDecimal(double val) {
        super(val);
    }
```

which I'd hope it would allow me to use a regular floating point number in my query/mutation, but it doesn't seem to work that way. Basically if the below is a BestDecimal object, I want this to work just as if it were a BigDecimal.

```
myquery(number: 10){
  whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 things you can do.

- Map you class as a custom scalar. To do this, you have to implement as custom `TypeMapper` and wire it in.
- Alternatively, you can provide a custom `TypeAdapter` that adapts `BestDecimal` to `BigDecimal` and vice versa.

Check out the existing implementations of `TypeMapper` or `TypeAdapter`, e.g. [OptionalIntAdapter](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/blob/master/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/generator/mapping/common/OptionalIntAdapter.java) (that makes `OptionalInt` act as an `Integer`), and make a new one based on that. Or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57391803/294657) for a custom scalar.

You can hook it up using `generator.withTypeMappers`or `generator.withTypeAdapters`.

Using the Spring Starter, you can add a `TypeMapper` like this:

```
@Bean
public ExtensionProvider<GeneratorConfiguration, TypeMapper> mappers() {
    //After IdAdapter is generally a safe place to insert custom mappers
    return (config, mappers) -> mappers.insertAfter(IdAdapter.class, new YouCustomMapper());
}
```

You can't wire a `TypeAdapter` directly, unfortunately. You'd have to wire it as a `TypeMapper`, `InputConverter` and `OutputConverter` at the same time, which is annoying. So instead, it's easier to add a custom module that adds a `TypeAdapter`:

```
@Bean
public ExtensionProvider<GeneratorConfiguration, Module> modules() {
    return (config, modules) -> modules.append(context -> 
         context.getSchemaGenerator().withTypeAdapters(new YourCustomAdapter()));
}
```

You can (and should) of course make a proper `Module` class instead of an anonymous one like I did.